# Masking URL, Subdomain redirection

Tags: apache-2.2, rewrite, httpd.conf, tomcat7

We have hosted a Java web application for **www.domain.com** on Apache & Tomcat.

I have two problems, as follows

1) Directory Index in Apache lists **home.jsp** ahead of **redirect.jsp**. For my domain.com in the **web.xml**, I have maintained redirect.jsp as the **welcome file**. However, when I visit www.domain.com, ***home.jsp is being rendered.***

2) In an attempt to resolve problem 1 above, I maintained an entry in htaccess - **DirectoryIndex redirect.jsp**. Though this resolves the above problem, this creates a different problem for me, as follows.

Subdomains on domain.com need to be redirected to **home.jsp** of a different domain **abc.com**. The problem that is happening now is that when I try to access **xyz.domain.com**, though it is being redirected to abc.com, but the **redirect.jsp page of abc.com** is being rendered when actually home.jsp should be rendered. So, it seems the htaccess directory index is being carried forward to abc.com

I need to know what I am doing wrong & what is the best way to set this up on Apache & Tomcat.

Answer (score 0):

Maintain your DirectoryIndex home.jsp.

To solve your #1 problem, instead of putting DirectoryIndex redirect.jsp in the htaccess of www.domain.com, use ModRewrite instead:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^$ redirect.jsp
```

(I only tested this in PHP environment, but should work if you have mod_rewrite in your Apache)